# SQL: Multiple SELECTs instead of JOIN

Tags: sql-server, join, union

I am not completely new to SQL, but this time I am slow on the uptake.
For a data export, I have to select some user data including two JOINs. The data is not related, I just need both information in one export sheet.

I have created a example. The column *groupname* is from one JOIN and the column *course* from the other JOIN:

```
╔════╦═══════════╦══════════╦═══════════╦════════════╗
║ id ║ firstname ║ lastname ║ groupname ║   course   ║
╠════╬═══════════╬══════════╬═══════════╬════════════╣
║  1 ║ John      ║ Doe      ║ Manager   ║ Management ║
║  1 ║ John      ║ Doe      ║ CEO       ║ Management ║
║  1 ║ John      ║ Doe      ║ Manager   ║ Logistics  ║
║  1 ║ John      ║ Doe      ║ CEO       ║ Logistics  ║
║  1 ║ John      ║ Doe      ║ Manager   ║ Leadership ║
║  1 ║ John      ║ Doe      ║ CEO       ║ Leadership ║
╚════╩═══════════╩══════════╩═══════════╩════════════╝
```

Due to the nature of JOINS; the groupname-column is duplicated now several times. But what I actually want, is something like this:

```
╔════╦═══════════╦══════════╦═══════════╦════════════╗
║ id ║ firstname ║ lastname ║ groupname ║   course   ║
╠════╬═══════════╬══════════╬═══════════╬════════════╣
║  1 ║ John      ║ Doe      ║ Manager   ║            ║
║  1 ║ John      ║ Doe      ║ CEO       ║            ║
║  1 ║ John      ║ Doe      ║           ║ Management ║
║  1 ║ John      ║ Doe      ║           ║ Logistics  ║
║  1 ║ John      ║ Doe      ║           ║ Leadership ║
╚════╩═══════════╩══════════╩═══════════╩════════════╝
```

I guess, doing two SELECT-Statements consecutively would be the better option. Unfortunately, the original query with JOINS and where-Arguments has like 25 lines of code, so I would not like to duplicate it.
Is there a way to achieve my way of output more easily then doing for example a UNION with two long queries (see below for simple example in this case)?

```
SELECT u.[id]
      ,[firstname]
      ,[lastname]
      ,groupname
      ,'' AS course
  FROM [dbo].[users] u
  JOIN dbo.groups g ON u.id = g.userId
UNION ALL
SELECT u.[id]
      ,[firstname]
      ,[lastname]
      ,'' AS groupname
      ,course
  FROM [dbo].[users] u
  JOIN dbo.courses c ON u.id = c.userId
```

Comment: can you provide some sample data from each table ?

Comment: This is not MySQL syntax, this is ms sql. Removed the MySQL tag.

Comment: `union all` is pretty much as good as it gets for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think their is a lot of way to solve your problem. I will give you the best way I can think of.

**First Solution** : Simply use a `WITH` not to repeat your common part query as follow:

```
WITH CommonPart (id, firstname, lastname)
AS
(
    Select id, firstname, lastname
    From [dbo].[users]
    -- Eventually a filter ...
)

SELECT cp.*
  , g.groupname
  , '' AS course
FROM CommonPart cp
JOIN dbo.groups g ON cp.id = g.userId
UNION ALL
SELECT cp.*
  ,'' AS groupname
  ,c.course
FROM CommonPart cp
JOIN dbo.courses c ON cp.id = c.userId
```

**Second Solution** : You can Insert null values into `courses` and `groups` and use a simple LEFT JOIN. But I don't like this second solution.

EDIT: After Insert of null values, it would look like:

```
Select  u.id,
        u.firstname,
        u.lastname,
        g.groupname,
        c.course
From [dbo].[users] u
Left Join [dbo].[groups] g ON g.userId = u.id
Left Join [dbo].[courses] c ON c.userId = u.id
Where (g.groupname IS NULL and c.course IS NOT NULL) 
  OR  (g.groupname IS NOT NULL and c.course IS NULL)
```

Comment: The first solution works like a charme. I did not think of using WITH. Normally, I only use it for recursion. The only drawback is that I have to reorder the order of columns in another query (I am using this code in a table-valued-function in order to use parameters for filters)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a Table-Valued UDF with the query in question and then make a UNION ALL with the two UDFs

**Pro:**
- Much shorter Query:

```
SELECT * FROM [MY_UDF](Param 1, Param 2, ...)<br/>
UNION ALL<br/>
SELECT * FROM [MY_UDF](Different Param 1, Different Param 2, ...)
```

**Con:**
- You have to create the table valued UDF.

Otherwise: I think `QUERY_1 UNION ALL QUERY_2` is probably the way to go.